# What is the Playwright equivalent of Selenium's ExecuteScript function?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium-webdriver, playwright

In Selenium (c#), you can use an `IJavaScriptExecutor` to execute javascript commands on `IWebElement`s you find, using the `arguments[index]` string in your script. For example, if I want to use javascript to click on an element, I could use the following code to do so:

```cs
((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", driver.FindElement(location));
```

In PlayWright, I know we have access to the `Page.evaluate` method, which lets us run custom javascript functions, but for the life of me, I can't figure out how to find the element I want to click on for the javascript method.

I have tried using a couple of things I found on the internet, but they haven't been working, even in situations where I know it works when I run it in selenium. Here's one example of what I've tried:

```cs
string clickScript = "var aTags = document.getElementsByTagName(\"option\");\r\n" +
"var searchText = \"Card\";rln" +
"var found; \r\n" +
"\r\n" +
"for (var i = 0; i < aTags. length; i+) {\r\n" +
"    if (aTags[i] textContent == searchText) {\r\n" +
"        found = aTags[i];\r\n" +
"        break; \r\n" +
"    }r\n" +
"}r\n" +
"\r\n" +
"found.click();"
    
await Page.evaluate(() => clickScript);
```

This compiles and runs, and I don't get any errors, but it just doesn't click on the element. My Javascript knowledge is very basic, and I've tried a few different scripts I've found, but none of them actually interact with the element.

However, when I use `((IJavaScriptExecutor)driver).ExecuteScript("arguments[0].click()", driver.FindElement(location));`, selenium is able to interact with the element without any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach as well.

```
var locator = page.Locator("some_selector");
await locator.EvaluateAsync("element => element.click()");
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to pass a string to `EvaluateAsync`:

```
await page.EvaluateString(@"() => {
    ///your lines of code
}");
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answer listed pointed out what the problem was with my specific code. For anybody else who may come here looking for answers, here's what I'm doing:

```
await Page.EvaluateAsync("document.getElementById(\"id\").click();");
```

This finds the element by the id, and then calls the `element.click()` method. This has worked in every situation that it does for selenium.

Comment: Huh, that's weird. The javascript isn't async so the other answer is probably better. I wasn't expecting c# when I clicked to get here so I don't know what can go wrong.

Comment: The JavaScript isn't async, but I need the call to the browser to be async

Comment: If you're not returning anything it doesn't matter. If you are, and the code is async, then you will have to resolve it properly. I'm not sure how it works here but selenium passes a callback function to execute_async_script

Comment: So, as a general note, playwright is asynchronous, and almost all of the methods have `Async` in their name.

Comment: Yes, I'm not sure why it has 2 methods for that, regular playwright (js version) doesn't.